# How to use "createStackNavigator" and "createMaterialTopTabNavigator" together?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

On my react native app i was using "createStackNavigator" but when i combine "createMaterialTopTabNavigator" it gives Error. How can i use both navigation ? I tried aolot but did not able to resolve this issue. In my code i use createStackNavigator two times one for home and other for tabScreen both work fine when i use seperatly it work but cannot able to combine.

**Main.js**

```
const Home = createStackNavigator(
    { 
        Profile: Profile,
        Feed: Feed,
        Chemein: Chemein,
        Graph: Graph,
    },
      {
          initialRouteName: 'Profile',

            defaultNavigationOptions: { 
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#744DD2',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
        },
    },

);

const TabScreen = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        Clubs: { screen: Clubs },
        Members: { screen: Members },
    },
    {
        tabBarPosition: 'top',
        swipeEnabled: true,
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#ffff',
            inactiveTintColor: '#ccc',
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#744DD2',
            },
        },
    }
);

const TopTab = createStackNavigator({
    TabScreen: {
        screen: TabScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#744DD2',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
            title: 'Clubs',
        },
    },
});

 const container = createAppContainer(Home);
// const container = createAppContainer(TabScreen );

 export default container;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive done somthing like this :

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppStack,
    Notification: Notifications,
    Account: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) =>
        getTabBarIcon(navigation, focused, tintColor),
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.tealC,
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  },
);
```

And my `appstack` is my stack navigator with the code below :

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: {
      screen: Home,
    },
    AirportMeeting: {
      screen: AirportMeeting,
    },
    MeetingPoint: {
      screen: MeetingPoint,
    },
    DriverDetails: {
      screen: DriverDetails,
    },
    SightSeeing: {
      screen: SightSeeing,
    },
    HotelDetails: {
      screen: HotelDetails,
    },
    FlightDetails: {
      screen: FlightDetails,
    },
    AddSight: {
      screen: AddSight,
    },
    SightSeeingPurchase: {
      screen: SightSeeingPurchase,
    },
    AddMeals: {
      screen: AddMeals,
    },
    HomeCard: {
      screen: HomeCard,
    },
    Trips: {
      screen: Trips,
    },
    FAQ: {
      screen: FAQ,
    },
    Support: {
      screen: Support,
    },
    BeforeTravel: {
      screen: BeforeTravel,
    },
    Weather: {
      screen: Weather,
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false,
    },
    initialRouteName: 'HomeCard',
    transitionConfig: () => fromRight(),
  },
);
```

So basically in my home route of tabnavigator ive used Appstack which is a stack navigator.

Just in case you are curious, ive alos made a switchnavigator where ive added tab navigator and other stack navigtors too, so everythings possible:

```
const navigation = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      App: TabNavigator,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Both are in same file ?

Comment: The question was about createMaterialTopTabNavigator. Could you provide an example for this?